# Outputting compiled babel files to the same folder level

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

How do I output compiled babel files in the same level as the files. I currently have my script to read the source folder and output the compiled file in a separate folder that retains the folder structure using the code in my package.json

```
  "build:lib": "./node_modules/.bin/babel src/components/ --out-dir lib",
```

say I have a react component in src/components/Button/Button.js. I want to compile the minified version in src/components/Button/Button.minified.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File extension options reference: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli#set-file-extensions

```
"build:lib": "./node_modules/.bin/babel src/components/ --out-dir src/components/ --out-file-extension .minified.js",
```

Note: this isn't minified, but transpiled?  I don't see where you used a minifier?

Comment: ah yes you're right. just transpiled. can you recommend a good minifier tool? uglify?

Comment: uglify is pretty standard ya.  terser is pretty good too